# Equivalent of org.apache.axis.components.net.SunFakeTrustSocketFactory for wsimport

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, axis, wsimport

When I generate webservice client stubs using Apache Axis, I disable the server certificate trust check in my code using the client stubs by calling the following method

```
AxisProperties.setProperty("axis.socketSecureFactory",
     "org.apache.axis.components.net.SunFakeTrustSocketFactory");
```

How do I disable the trust check with client stubs that were generated by running `wsimport`?

I use this when I am running some test code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All that's happening in that class is the provision of a bogus [trust store manager](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/axis/axis/1.4/org/apache/axis/components/net/SunFakeTrustSocketFactory.java#SunFakeTrustSocketFactory), that [trusts anything](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/axis/axis/1.4/org/apache/axis/components/net/SunFakeTrustSocketFactory.java#87). Knowing that, you can use [this article](http://schrepfler.blogspot.com.br/2009/06/relaxing-ssl-validation-for-jaxws.html) and put something together.

1. First the [easy trust manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/X509TrustManager.html)

   ```
   public class EasyTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
     public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
           //do nothing
     }

     public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
          //do nothing
     }

     public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
          return null;
     }
   }
   ```
2. Then feed your trust manager to an instance of [`SSLContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html), just like [axis was doing](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/axis/axis/1.4/org/apache/axis/components/net/SunFakeTrustSocketFactory.java#53):

   ```
   SSLContext sCtxt = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL"); 
   sCtxt.init(null, new TrustManager[]{new EasyTrustManager()}, new java.security.SecureRandom());
   ```
3. Setup the custom context, by calling `HttpsURLConnection#setDefaultSSLSocketFactory` based on the fact that all your web service calls are based on an underlying instance of `HttpsURLConnection`. This call will setup the context, by way of `SSLContext#getContext`, for *all* https calls

   ```
   HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sCtxt.getSocketFactory());
   ```

Comment: Had to edit your EasyTrustManager to make it compile.